# #Python, PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I am encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home_dir_conf.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(conf_dir_path, "w") as msg_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\svaleriev\\.python-course-home-dir-conf'
```

Here's the code I'm currently using: https://pastebin.com/ujgkWsXh

```py
import os

home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")

conf_dir = "python-course-home-dir-conf"
conf_dir_path = os.path.join(home_dir, conf_dir)
os.makedirs(conf_dir_path, exist_ok=True)

conf_file_name = "message.conf"
conf_file_path = os.path.join(conf_dir_path, conf_file_name)
print(conf_dir_path)

DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Change me!"
if os.path.exists(conf_file_path):
    with open(conf_file_path) as msg_file:
        message = msg_file.read()
        print(f"Configured message: {message}")
else:
    with open(conf_dir_path, "w") as msg_file:
        msg_file.write(DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
        print(f"Message set!")
```

Can someone provide guidance on what is causing this error and how to address it?

Comment: You seem to be creating a directory (`makedirs(conf_dir_path...)`) and trying to open it as if it were a file (`open(conf_dir_path...`) in your `else:` block. Did you mean `open(conf_file_path, "w")` ?

Comment: You used the wrong variable. Change it to conf_file_path.

Comment: Yes, misspelled conf_file_path with conf_file_dir and I was trying to open directory.. not a file. Thanks to all, a very nice community. I wasn't expecting rapid answers as I use stackoverflow for very first time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must replace

```
else:
    with open(conf_dir_path, "w") as msg_file:
        msg_file.write(DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
        print(f"Message set!")
```

by

```
else:
    with open(conf_file_path, "w") as msg_file:
        msg_file.write(DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
        print(f"Message set!")
```

Answer (score 0):

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

indicates that the program does not have the necessary permissions to write to the specified file or directory.

To solve it you can run the program as an administrator

Comment: No, the problem is that OP used the wrong variable and ended up trying to open a directory, not a file. And more generally, one should only run as admin when there is a genuine administrative task to perform. Its a risky thing to do.